# Foundation zurb in different browsers

Tags: django, zurb-foundation

I have build a simple html template for my django project using foundation zurb and when open the webpage in firefox it looks right but when I'm doing the same in chrome I get no styles on the website. Any suggestion?

Comment: Think to update Foundation, this issue is perhaps resolved

Answer (score 1):

Many times, inconsistencies between browsers are due to errors in your markup.  Some browsers automatically fix certain errors, and not others, and other browsers don't fix errors at all.  Run all your html through [this](http://validator.w3.org/) and check Chrome's console for errors.

If you'd like more in depth answers, please provide markup.